# Extract whole row/line using Lumenworks CSV Parser

Tags: vb.net, lumenworks

How do I read the whole row while using `LumenWorks` CVS parser? So far am only able to read entry by entry but not the whole row. i.e. if a row is `a,b,c,d,e,f`, am able to pluck out each individual alphabet. However, I want to be able to read the whole row

Currently I have:

```
my_csv = New CsvReader(New StreamReader(file_path), False, ",", resetPoint)
field_count = my_csv.FieldCount
While my_csv.ReadNextRecord()
    'process the data here
    'This code will process each individual alphabet in one row
```

The above reads each individual alphabet. What I want is to have something like

`row = my_csv.row`

Is this option available or something similar?

**'EDITED'**

When you have basic VB programming skills like me, this is what you come up with to solve the problem

```
Dim my_string As String = ""
        For x As Integer = 0 To my_csv.FieldCount - 1
            my_string += my_csv(x).ToString.Trim + ","
        Next
        my_string = Mid(my_string, 1, Len(my_string) - 1)
        Return my_string
```

By all means use the code in the marked answer. Its super elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found anything available, but this should work:

VB:

```
Dim rowFields = Enumerable.Range(0, my_csv.FieldCount).
   Select(Function(field) my_csv(CInt(my_csv.CurrentRecordIndex), field))
Dim line As String = String.Join(my_csv.Delimiter.ToString(), rowFields)
```

C#:

```
var rowFields = Enumerable.Range(0, my_csv.FieldCount)
    .Select(field => my_csv[(int)my_csv.CurrentRecordIndex, field]);
string line = string.Join(my_csv.Delimiter.ToString(), rowFields);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked spot on. Code way more elegant than what I had come up with. Mind explaining the code? I don't understand the `select(function....`

Answer (score 1):

I found a method using the `CopyCurrentRecordTo(array)` method, which seems to be marginally faster (a few seconds) the wider (more columns) a file is:

C#:

```
string[] currentRow = new string[csv.FieldCount];
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
  csv.CopyCurrentRecordTo(currentRow);
  var line = string.Join(csv.Delimiter.ToString(), currentRow);
}
```

VB (this is from Telerik converter, beware):

```
Dim currentRow As String() = New String(csv.FieldCount - 1) {}
While csv.ReadNextRecord()
    csv.CopyCurrentRecordTo(currentRow)
    Dim line = String.Join(csv.Delimiter.ToString(), currentRow)
End While
```